# JMS Custom message ordering

Tags: jms, message

JMS Question:- Is there any way to change the messages order in JMSQUEUE based on custom rule/policy/strategy? Other then FIFO..

Comment: Depends on the JMS implementation.

Comment: Could you give an example of the alternate ordering behavior you're thinking of?

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting JMSPriority property on the messages sent to the queue. JMSPriority can have value from 0 to 9, with 9 been the highest. If multiple messages are present in  the queue then the message with the highest priority will be consumed first.

This link could be helpful for you,

http://www.techpaste.com/2012/04/prioritize-messages-enqueued-jms-queue/